# npm module with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, webpack

I'm writing a npm module with TypeScript. Lets say I have this tree in my library:

```
.
├── README.md
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   └── index.js
├── lib
│   └── index.ts
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── test
│   └── test.js
└── tsconfig.json
```

And in my `package.json` I have this:

```
{
    "name": "mylib",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "description": "A Node.js module",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^2.5.3"
    }
}
```

in tsconfig.json —default config— I have:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

in `dist/index.ts` I have:

```
export function appendtext(str: string): string {
    return str + ' world';
}
```

And I call this library like:

```
var mylib = require('mylib');
var result = mylib.appendtext('Hello');
```

Question 1: When I call `mylib` from my application `myapp`, `myapp` wont build it; it will only use the compiled code at `dist/`. Is this correct?

Question 2: If `1` is correct, then I can split the source code at `lib/index.ts` in different modules and compile them with WebPack when developing `mylib`. The resulting code will be saved at `dist/`, and this is the code that `myapp` will use. So, again, `myapp` wont need to compile the modules of `mylib`, as it will use the already linked code at `dist/`.

Thanks for this clarifications!

Comment: when u use ts with node..usually `import * as something from 'something';`..also in your package.json: u can try `"scripts": {
        "build": "tsc -w"
    }`

Comment: also u need to show what is your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Hi, thanks! Added basic tsconfig.json info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, only the built code from `dist/` will be run.

Question 2: Yes, you can split index.ts into multiple files or modules. In general you probably don't want to use webpack at this level though - that's better left for the final end application in most cases. It's unnecessary (the end application will normally be using webpack or similar anyway) and can make debugging etc more complicated by making it harder to find the 'real' code that's being executed.

Instead, you can split into multiple files still using just `tsc` and they will *all* end up in `dist/`, linked together by internal `require()` calls like any normal node module, and that will work fine. Alternatively, if you need to split into totally separate modules, just follow that same pattern for each one separately, so they all export JavaScript files + types, and you can import them as normal from the next module.

Comment: Hi @TimPerry, thank you very much. In `2.`, you say that Webpack _It's unnecessary (the end application will normally be using webpack or similar anyway)_. But then we are assuming that the end app will use a linker/compiler like WebPack. What if `myapp` dont use it?

Comment: It depends on the environment (web, node, ...other?), and why you aren't using bundling. If you're building anything substantial for web you need bundling really, both for performance and because you need it for almost all npm dependencies. Meanwhile in node, these commonjs modules will work out of the box with no bundling. What's the situation, and why isn't `myapp` being bundled?

Comment: One interesting option by the way is ES modules, which are now widely natively supported, which gives you modules on the web without bundling. For that case you can make TypeScript output CommonJS & ESM directly. See https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal for an example (and https://unpkg.com/react-reverse-portal/ for the result).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thinking about it, is true, any app that may use this library will need a bundler anyway. ES modules is an alternative, but only with TypeScript I can compile the code to Javascript, and left the linking to the bundler of the app.